# Handling SCD type 2 table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
id  c1  c2  c3

A   Y   Y   N
B   Y   N   Y
C   Y   Y   N
C   Y   Y   N
D   Y   Y   N
D   N   N   Y
E   Y   Y   N
E   Y   N   N
E   N   Y   N
F   Y   Y   N
F   Y   Y   N
G   Y   N   N
G   Y   N   Y
```

I want to check if c1 and c3 value for the same id has one 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N', if c2 value for the same id has ONE 'N' then 'N' ELSE 'Y', as follows:

```
id  c1 c2 c3
A   Y  Y  N
B   Y  N  Y
C   Y  Y  N
D   Y  N  Y
E   Y  N  N
.
.
.
```

i have no idea what to do !

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Maybe elaborate.

Comment: @stickybit I edit it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use aggregation.

```
SELECT id,
       max(c1) c1,
       min(c2) c2,
       max(c3) c3
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY id;
```